# i want to save each vectordb from choma and load it, and combinat all vectordb for training

Tags: python, chatbot, openai-api, langchain

this is code, I want to create application chat bot, this application can train from multiples files those files are stored in storage and user can managed those files after trained by add another file to trained bot or delete it:

```
load_dotenv('.env')

documents = []
# Create a List of Documents from all of our files in the ./docs folder
for file in os.listdir("docs"):
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        pdf_path = "./docs/" + file
        loader = PyPDFLoader(pdf_path)
        documents.extend(loader.load())
    elif file.endswith('.docx') or file.endswith('.doc'):
        doc_path = "./docs/" + file
        loader = Docx2txtLoader(doc_path)
        documents.extend(loader.load())
    elif file.endswith('.txt'):
        text_path = "./docs/" + file
        loader = TextLoader(text_path)
        documents.extend(loader.load())

# Split the documents into smaller chunks
text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=10)
documents = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

# Convert the document chunks to embedding and save them to the vector store
vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(documents, embedding=OpenAIEmbeddings(), persist_directory="./data")
vectordb.persist()

# create our Q&A chain
pdf_qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.7, model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo'),
    retriever=vectordb.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'k': 6}),
    return_source_documents=True,
    verbose=False
)

yellow = "\033[0;33m"
green = "\033[0;32m"
white = "\033[0;39m"

chat_history = []
print(f"{yellow}---------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print('Welcome to the DocBot. You are now ready to start interacting with your documents')
print('---------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
while True:
    query = input(f"{green}Prompt: ")
    if query == "exit" or query == "quit" or query == "q" or query == "f":
        print('Exiting')
        sys.exit()
    if query == '':
        continue
    result = pdf_qa(
        {"question": query, "chat_history": chat_history})
    print(f"{white}Answer: " + result["answer"])
    chat_history.append((query, result["answer"]))
```